# How to pass the RGPD popup / iframe with Selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, frame

Ok, attempt to use Selenium on a website : lefigaro.fr, but no class related to the RGPD popup to be found by Selenium, even after a switch to frame. :/

I'm juste looking a reliable way to close it.

It goes this way :

```
from selenium import webdriver
WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"
ADRESSE = 'https://www.lefigaro.fr/'

driver = webdriver.Firefox() #the chrome version was even worse, geckodriver a the root
driver.get(ADRESSE)

elt = driver.find_element_by_class_name("sc-18sn7k8-1") #error
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
elt = driver.find_element_by_class_name("sc-18sn7k8-1") #error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to iframe via index.

It seems that popup is the only iframe on the page, so perhaps this will work:

driver.switch_to.frame(0) # or perhaps (1)

**EDIT:**

It seems the page already is in an iframe when it loads.

Do `driver.switch_to.default_content()` first.

Then it seems the iframe you want is (3):

```
driver.switch_to.frame(3)
```

Hope this works.

Hmm, actually, not quite... I'll spend some more time on this.

Comment: Already tried, both got the "NoSuchElementException"

Comment: Ok that was it, thanks, I dealt with it through :

`driver.switch_to.default_content()`

`driver.switch_to.frame(2)`

`elt = driver.find_element_by_class_name("button__skip")`

`elt.click()`